# How to read from a file that has no extension in Java?

Tags: java, programming-languages

So basically say i have a file that is simply called settings, however it has no extension, but contains the data of a text file renamed.
How can i load this into the file() method in java? 
simply using the directory and file seems to make java think its just a directory and not a file.

Thanks

Comment: can you post some sample code to show us what you are doing?

Comment: well lets say i have: 
String s = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Application Data\\settings";
so we are looking at the file settings in the app data folder, however using:
file = new File(s);

and trying to read from it does not work.

Comment: are you sure that the file has no extension? some operating systems are known to hide them.

Comment: Can you show us the code that you're using? I can only think of improper appending taking place. Or worse still, you're not seeing the extension of the file because it is hidden by default under Windows machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, and on unix, and even on the filesystem level on windows, there is no difference in if a file has an extension or not.

Just the Windows Explorer, and maybe its pendants on Linux, use the extension to show an appropriate icon for the file, and to choose the application to start the file with, if it is selected with a double click or in similar ways.

In the filesystem there are only typed nodes, and there can be file nodes like "peter" and "peter.txt", and there can be folder nodes named "peter" and "peter.txt".

So, to conclude, in Java there is really no difference in file handling regarding the extension.

Comment: thank you, i have no idea why it didnt work, i changed a few things around and it works now, thanks to everyone!

Comment: Not sure if this is true. In Windows, until I changed my folder view options to include the extension of the file name in the folder, my java source code Scanner would not read in the `dbase.txt` that I was asking it to read.

Comment: @SeesSound: Java definitely does not change its behaviour, when you change the view settings in Explorer. Garanteed.

Answer (score 1):

`new File("settings")` should work fine. Java does not treat files with or without extension differently.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't understand file extensions and doesn't treat a file any differently based on its extension, or lack of extension.  If Java thinks a `File` is a directory, then it is a directory.  I suspect this is not what is happening.  Can you try?

```
File file = new File(filename);
System.out.println('\'' + filename + "'.isDirectory() is "+file.isDirectory());
System.out.println('\'' +filename + "'.isFile() is "+file.isFile());
```

BTW: On Unix, a file `file.` is different to `file` which is different to `FILE`. AFAIK on Windows/MS-DOS they are treated as the same.

Answer (score 0):

The extension should not make a difference.  Can you post us the code you are using? And the error message please (stack trace).

Something along these lines should do the trick (taken from http://www.kodejava.org/examples/241.html)

```
//
// Create an instance of File for data file.
//
File file = new File("data");

try {
    //
    // Create a new Scanner object which will read the data 
    // from the file passed in. To check if there are more 
    // line to read from it we check by calling the 
    // scanner.hasNextLine() method. We then read line one 
    // by one till all line is read.
    //
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```